# How I can run two controllers via two routing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two modules, where two routes:

```
angular
  .module('lang', ['ngRoute'])
  .config('lang', ['$routeProvider', config])
  .controller('lang', lang);

function config(route){
  route.when('/:lang/:page', {
    template    : '',
    controller  : lang
  })
}
```

and route for guide module:

```
angular
  .module('guide', ['ngRoute'])
  .config('guide', ['$routeProvider', config])
  .controller('guide', guide);

function config(route){
  route.when('/:lang/guide', {
    template    : '/view/guide.html',
    controller  : guide
  })
}
```

But the second controller not run. How can I run two controllers using two routes?

Answer (score 0):

ng-route using for SPA applications.

> If you want to navigate to different pages in your application, but you also want the application to be a SPA (Single Page Application), with no page reloading, you can use the ngRoute module.

Therefore you need to define main module, config routes there and inject dependencies. Example:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute', 'firstModule', 'secondModule']);
var configFunction = function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
 .when('/:lang/:page', {
  templateUrl: '/view/guide.html',
  controller : 'FirstCtrl'
})    
 .when('/:lang/guide', {
  templateUrl: '/view/guide2.html',
  controller: 'SecondCtrl'
})
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

app.config(configFunction);

app.config(['$locationProvider',
    function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');       
    }]);
```

And this is your injected controllers :

```
var app = angular.module('firstModule', []);
app.controller('FirstCtrl',function(){});

var app = angular.module('secondModule', []);
app.controller('SecondCtrl',function(){});
```

Be aware regarding syntax. Check syntax for Angular version you use.